# Is there a way to use Twitter Digits and skip the first page that is the button and enter in the main page that ask phone number

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making an app that uses twitter digits, and I was wondering if there is a way to use skip the  twitter digits button screen that says "use my phone number" and directly it asks for entering the phone number screen.Can it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I use Digit in past so answer may be not so accurate. But my idea is to click on this button programmatically with `onClick()` method. It's like workaround but maybe help you to get some ideas.